# Question has not been migrated but has answer from non-user?

Tags: support, users

[This recent question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101069/how-the-uploaded-images-are-managed-in-file-system-and-mysql-database) (asked 5 hours ago) was answered (and *accepted*) 2 hours ago by a user that does not appear to have an account on this site. It was also edited by the same user just 1 hour ago.

[image: Non user answered and edited]

This sort of thing can happen when a question has been migrated from another site (where the user does have an account), however, this question does not appear to have been migrated and this user has continued to make edits.

How is this possible?

---

**EDIT:** Another answer on the same question (now "deleted by owner") is showing the same thing. However, when I looked at the question earlier I'm pretty sure it was an active (new) user that posted the answer? Are these users deleting their accounts?!

Comment: It seems possible that they are deleting their accounts.   You can do so if you have never voted and have posted at most once: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account

Comment: The answer OP deleted their own account.